# Passing dynamic objects

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

There is a set of objects in a php project. I will represent them as JSON

```
{
  "name" : "foo",
  "type" : "bar",
  "context" : {
      //There is an arbitrary set of fields in which there can be integers, float, string, bool, as well as dictionaries and arrays
  }
}
```

How I can wrap this objects in `proto`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store arbitrary JSON in Protocol Buffers, you can use `google.protobuf.Value`, from [struct.proto](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/struct.proto). In each language there's a way to convert JSON into protobuf, and with this type you can handle arbitrary JSON.